# Access WebExtensions API from the Browser Console

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-console

Is it possible? I'd like to experiment with some functions in a REPL.

Comment: @JJJ, I rolled back your edit and am against the close vote. You probably don't aware what the Browser Console is, it is a specific instrument inside Firefox, similar to [tag:web-console], but which works in a browser context instead of a tab context, see the link in the answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do so from the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console).

However, you can if are debugging your WebExtension (accessed though `about:debugging`➞Debug) using the [Add-on Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger) *and* your WebExtension has a background page (i.e. you have a defined a `page` or `script` in a [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) entry in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json)):

[image: Using chrome APIs in Add-on Debugger]

Comment: Thanks. A background script was enough. Took [this](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/commands) as a basis, added needed permissions, and got the desired console with `browser`.